# Extract snippet using specific keywords

Tags: php, python

Is there a predefined library/function in **php** or python that would let me extract 2-3 paragraphs out of a complete document based on the proximity of the keywords to be found in the document.
Let's say i have 5 keywords, A,B,C,D,E. And I have an essay containing multiple occurrences of all these keywords.
I would like to extract a few paragraphs from it which contain the closest occurrences of the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Probably split/explode on new lines and the enumerate through the ones you want.

```
text = """Test paragraph 1.

Test paragraph 2.

Test paragraph 3.

Test paragraph 4."""

paragraphs = text.split("\n\n")

print(paragraphs[1:3])
```